# Das deutsche Verwandte zum englischen »queen« und zum schwedischen »kvinna«

Tags: word-usage, meaning, etymology, history

In einer laienlinguistischen Unterhaltung ist gestern plötzlich die Frage aufgetaucht, was denn *Frau* auf Schwedisch heiße; die Antwort war *kvinna.* Sofort ist mir aufgefallen, dass das kognat – linguistisch verwandt – mit dem englischen Wort *queen* sein müsste. Und da sich Kognate in der Regel in allen Sprachen finden, die sich aus einem gemeinsamen Vorläufer entwickelt haben, müsste es auch ein entsprechend verwandtes Wort im Deutschen geben.<sup>†</sup>

Es ist mir aber nicht geläufig, muss also irgendwann in historischer Zeit von bedeutungsverwandten Wörtern abgelöst oder verdrängt worden sein.

- Welches Wort (oder vielleicht gar: welche Wörter) sind etymologisch mit *queen/kvinna* verwandt?
- Was war die Bedeutung dieses Worts (näher an *queen* oder näher an *kvinna*)?
- Lässt sich belegen, wann es außer Gebrauch geraten ist, und welches Wort es ersetzt hat?

---

†: Natürlich existiert für Eingeweihte der Name [Quina Quen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_IX#Quina_Quen), doch der ist eine Neuschöpfung und ausdrücklich *nicht* gemeint.

Comment: A first start? http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=queen

Comment: _Svenska Akademiens ordbok_ listet keine deutsche Verwandschaft auf: KVINNA kvin³a², f.; best. -an; pl. -or ((†) -er G1R 1: 163 1523. VDAkt. 1671, nr 19). (förr äv. q-. qvin- 1583 (: qwino want[er]). qvind- 1548 (: Quinde kniff[ue]r))
[fsv. qvinna; jfr d. kvinde, fd. qwinnæ, nor. kvinne, senisl. kvenna, kvinna; nybildning till fsv. qvinna (isl. kvenna), gen. pl. av KONA sbst.¹, o. förleden kvin(na)- i ssgr o. juxtapositioner, ävensom det koll. qvinde, kvinnor; besläktat med isl. kvǽn, kvinna, eng. queen, drottning. – Jfr KVINS]; eigentlich sind die recht zuverlässig in diesen Dingen.

Comment: Heute nur noch dialektale Reste, siehe http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=kone – ansonsten gibt es das Wort _wieder_ durch Import aus dem Griechischen (_androgyn_, _Gynäkologie_ usw.).

Comment: Ist jmd. gestorben?

Comment: Noch eine Anmerkung: _Norstedts etymologiska ordbok_ schreibt zu _kvinna_ es sei ursprünglich der Genetiv Plural von _kona_ , und es sei "ett gemensamt indoeuropeiskt ord med betydelsen 'hustru; kvinna; frilla; drottning' ...".

Comment: @userunknown Meinst du wegs dem Fußnotenzeichen?

Answer (score 8):

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Queene) gibt für das norddeutsche Wort *Queene* ([Färse](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausrind#Weibliche_Rinder_.28adult.29)) als Herkunft an:

> mittelniederdeutsch quene, altsächsisch quena = (alte) Frau

Comment: Endlich zahlen sich die Scrabble-Abende mit meiner Großmutter aus …

Comment: Diese Implikation, dass eine Königin mit einem Rind etymologisch verwandt sein soll … Das stellt selbst die Verwandtschaft von Ritter und Knecht in den Schatten =D