# Words in English sharing etymological roots with the German “toll”

Tags: etymology, english

Consider the German adjective *toll* meaning *great* or *mad.*

I am looking for the examples of English words (if any) containing some variation of *toll* and sharing some etymological root with *toll* (so having a meaning like *great* or *mad*).

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you please elaborate how general references such as dictionaries failed to help you? Otherwise your question may be closed. Also note that words with the same etymological origin may strongly deviate in meaning ([example](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/26758/2594)). By the way, the linguistic term for what you are looking is [*cognate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate).

Comment: The etymological root of the German word "toll" is not great but stupid/foolish. Did you read: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/toll and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toll

Comment: Thee meanings of the "toll" in English are usually tax, duty, damage which are far from the meaning "great". But perhaps there are some words in English partially containing some variant of "toll" (maybe at the middle or at the end) with the meaning "great" or "mad". I am looking for these words (if there exists any).

Comment: @Iris I have edited my question accordingly (I also added some explanation in my comment above).

Comment: English "toll" is **not** related to German "toll" but to German "Zoll". The shared root for English "toll" and German "Zoll" is Latin "telōnēum" and Greek "teloneíon".

Comment: @Iris I've never thought about that but now it raises the question how German "toll" became to mean "great". Perhaps similar story as for English "awesome" or "terrific".

Comment: @Em1, I did a quick search but I couldn't find an explaination. On the other hand, I didn't know about the change of meaning of "awesome" and "terrific".

Comment: Using this search: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=toll I found *dull*.

Comment: @CarstenS Using Google is a bit more efficient: https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&q=site:etymonline.com+%22german+toll%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: [This German question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35958/woher-kommt-die-redewendung-ding-aus-dem-dollhaus/35983#35983) about _Tollhaus_  is related.

Answer (score 10):

Both, the German *toll* and the English *[dull](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dull#English)* seem to originate from a common origin (Proto-Germanic *[dulaz](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Germanic/dulaz))* meaning something along the lines of *dazed, foolish, crazy, stupid.*

Quoting the [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toll#German) on *toll* (boldface mine):

> From Old High German *tol,* from Proto-Germanic **dulaz* ‎(“dazed, foolish, crazy, stupid”), **cognate with English *dull.***

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dull&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: How does this answer help with the request: "I am looking for the examples of English words (if any) containing some variation of toll and sharing some etymological root with toll (so having a meaning like great or mad)"?

Comment: @Iris: Because *dull* is a variation of *toll* that has the same etymological root?

Comment: Does dull has the meaning of great or mad?

Comment: @Iris: No, but it has a vaguely similar meaning. Also note that the part of the question that asks for a similar meaning is only an elaboration (at least that’s my understanding) of “sharing an etymological root”, as words from the same etymological root tend to have a similar meaning. However, in this case, language evolution has warped the meaning of the word quite a bit on both sides leading to *dull* and *toll* having almost an opposite meaning in the modern versions of the respective languages.