# Woher kommt die Redewendung "Ding aus dem Dollhaus"?

Tags: idiom

Relativ oft wird in meiner Familie (geographischer Ursprung Berlin und Brandenburg) eine überraschende oder unerwartete Situation als ein

```
Ding aus dem Dollhaus
```

bezeichnet.

Mich interessiert nun, ob man dieser Wortgruppe einen Ursprung zuweisen kann. Gibt es ein Theaterstück, ein Buch oder einen Artikel wo diese zum ersten Mal auftaucht?

Eine kurze Recherche via Suchmaschine ergab nichts außer verschiedene, jüngere Zeitungsartikel aus eben dieser Region.

Comment: Könnte es auch ein *Ding aus dem Tollhaus* sein?

Comment: Interessant, möglich ist es. Das ein `T` in Berlin mit der Zeit zum `D` wird, klingt nicht abwegig.

Comment: ...  *dass* ein `T` :) wenn ich mich nicht vertue.

Comment: Das ist richtig.

Comment: "Toll" (niederdeutsch "doll") bedeutete ursprünglich "verrückt", "irre" (siehe auch "Tollwut");
das "Tollhaus" wäre dann also ein Irrenhaus.

Comment: Tollhaus klingt gut, Dollhaus aber auch. Denken wir nur an ein *dolles Ding*. Daher habe ich bisher nie in Erwägung gezogen, dass es eventuell eine ausprachbedingte Abwandlung ist.

Comment: Im [plattdeutschen Wörterbuch des NDR](https://www.ndr.de/kultur/norddeutsche_sprache/plattdeutsch/woerterbuch101_abc-D.html) findet sich die Phrase "Dat is'n Ding ut'n Dullhus". Scheinbar wurde in Deiner Familie ein Mix aus Hoch- und Niederdeutsch überliefert - ergibt ja auch einen schönen Stabreim ;) Zur ursprünglichen Herkunft habe ich aber noch nichts gefunden

Comment: In Google Ngram finde ich die Phrase weder in Hoch- noch Niederdeutsch. Nur der Begriff [*Tollhaus*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tollhaus&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTollhaus%3B%2Cc0) taucht hier erstmals 1748 auf, hat ein Hoch um 1760 und dann noch mal einen kleineren Anstieg um 1800.  Viel älter kann die Redewendung also nicht sein...

Comment: @Marzipanherz Dein Kommentar sollte besser eine Antwort sein, glaube ich.

Comment: Ich würde eher fragen "wohin geht sie?". Ich kenne das absolut nicht als Redewendung - Nie gehört. Den Begriff "Tollhaus" als Synonym für "Klapsmühle" schon.

Comment: @tofro Dito, diese mutmaßliche Redewendung habe ich in vierzig Jahren nicht einmal gehört, „Tollhaus“ hingegen ist mir ebenso ein Begriff

Comment: Ich schon. Deshalb meine Frage.

Comment: @PatrickB: Auch ein *dolles Ding* ist doch aber eine sprachliche Abwandlung einer tollen Sache.

Answer (score 2):

Die Redewendung

> Ding aus dem Dollhaus

ist eine Mischung aus dem hochdeutschen

> Ding aus dem Tollhaus

sowie einer niederdeutschen Schreibweise, wie z.B.

> Ding ut'n Dullhus

Diese niederdeutsche Version wird im [plattdeutschen Wörterbuch des NDR](https://www.ndr.de/kultur/norddeutsche_sprache/plattdeutsch/woerterbuch101_abc-D.html) gelistet.

Die hochdeutsche Variange wird unter anderem auf [www.etymologie.info](http://www.etymologie.info/~e/d_/de-sprich.html) als Redewendung aufgeführt.

Einen eindeutigen Ursprung der Redewendung, wie ein bestimmtes Buch oder Theaterstück, konnte ich nicht finden.

Tollhäuser waren [Vorläufer von psychatrischen Kliniken](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychiatrische_Klinik#Vorformen), siehe hierzu auch die [Etymologie von *toll*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/toll#et-1).

Die Verwendung von *Ding aus dem Tollhaus* ist also vergleichbar mit *Ist ja irre!*.

Laut [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tollhaus&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1700&year_end=2017&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTollhaus%3B%2Cc0) taucht der Begriff *Tollhaus*   erstmals 1748 auf, hat ein Hoch um 1760 und dann noch mal einen kleineren Anstieg um 1800. Viel älter kann die Redewendung also nicht sein.

[image]